# How to add a subtype for a reference type in a live template?

Tags: intellij-idea, live-templates

I am trying to create a custom live template, which would create a Spring bean declaration.

This is a template text so far.

```
@Bean
public $TYPE$ $BEAN_NAME$() {
    return new $TYPE_SUBTYPE$();
}
```

and Template Variables configuration window

[image]

Everything works as intended BUT `$TYPE_SUBTYPE$` variable. I want it to use the first found subtype of `$TYPE$` or suggest subtypes of `$TYPE$`.

Instead of that, it gets populated with a type of `$TYPE$` and doesn't pick up a subtype, in my case a type that implements an interface used in `$TYPE$`.

Is it a bug?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Please report an issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: @y.bedrov I created the bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-59748

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the bug. The bug [was reported](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-59748) in Jetbrains Youtrack.

*Update 17/03/2021:* It still isn't fixed although they resolved it.